# Can't get element's style to change using a variable

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

So my script creates a element and changes it's innerHTML.

My problem is inside my script you can see this:

```
CurrentLine.innerHTML = '<p>' + user + " ⦙ " + size + " ⦙ "+ line + '<span id="LogColor" style="">' + color + '</span> </p>';
```

I'm needing help with this part of the innerHTML:

```
'<span id="LogColor" style="">' + obj.lineColor + '</span> </p>'
```

As you can see in my full script below after the child gets append. You see where I tried to change the span's style using a variable. It doesn't seem to change it's color though.

Full Script:

```
nvtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
var line = JSON.stringify(obj.line)
var size = JSON.stringify(obj.lineWidth)
var color = JSON.stringify(obj.lineColor) // Not needed, but defined anyways.


if (line == null)
{
//Do nothing..
}
else
{
var CurrentLine = document.createElement('p');
CurrentLine.innerHTML = '<p>' + user + " ⦙ " + size + " ⦙ "+ line + '<span 
id="LogColor" style="">' + color + '</span> </p>';
document.getElementById("LineConsole").appendChild(CurrentLine);
document.getElementById("LogColor").style.color = obj.lineColor;
}
```

The part I tried to change it's style.

```
document.getElementById("LogColor").style.color = obj.lineColor;
```

I even tried to do something like:

```
document.getElementById("LogColor").style = "color:" + color + ";"
```

Comment: What is the value of `obj.lineColor`? Additionally, it is not recommended to use `innerHTML` prop.

Comment: It's a hex value from a eventStream.

Comment: It can be a random hex value at any moment.

Comment: You need to assign a valid css color string like "#ffffff" or "rgb(255,255,255)"

Comment: CurrentLine name implies there are many lines but DOM allows only one id per document so you need to use a unique id (like add a running number) or use a class or just construct the object directly using document.createElement instead of innerHTML so you can assign its style/text directly.

Comment: Why won't this work?? ``document.getElementById("LogColor").style = "color:" + "#" + color + ";"``

Comment: This won't work as the browser will end it's html parsing before this gets compiled.

Comment: Just reference with the parent tag or class on parent tag with the LogColor. Put your html markup, I will show exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you are trying to do here but if you want the line you are adding to have the textcolor you could try:

```
'<span style="color:' + obj.lineColor + '">' + obj.lineColor + '</span> </p>'
```

provided your lineColor is a valid css color string like "red", "#ffffff" or "rgb(255,255,255)"

you would no longer need the id.